# Why deleting a bad question/answer doesn't return reputation points?

Tags: support, reputation, down-votes

It appears that after a bad question/answer removal the reputation points are not returned to the downvoters. Why is it so? Shouldn't it be different?

Answer (score 13):

[Downvotes on questions don't take rep from the voter.](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/vote-down)

[Deleted answers do restore rep lost from downvotes](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5222/244929) for both the poster and the voter, though it happens rather quietly. You should see a green +1 on your Achievements button but probably not any note about where it came from on the Achievements dropdown.

[Your profile reputation tab](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/users/current?tab=reputation) will list the events where you've been refunded that 1 reputation, along with a reason of "removed".

If something gets deleted and you don't see a change in rep instantly, be patient. The Stack often doesn't update this sort of thing immediately--either to give time for an accidental click to be undone, or because running the checks at regular intervals is more efficient.